# Code Igniter Cant upload File

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want to update my data on mysql with structure
| nip | nama | path1 | path2 |

i want to change by uploaded file name
this my view code

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/c_main/uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">Berkas 1</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="nip" id="nipUpload" value="">
            <input type="file" class="filestyle" name="berkas[]" data-buttonText="Find file" id="berkas[]">
            <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">Berkas 2</label>
            <input type="file" class="filestyle" name="berkas[]" data-buttonText="Find file" id="berkas[]">
            <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
  </div>

          <div class="row">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Upload File</button>
          </div>
</form>

this is my controller code

function uploadFile()
        {
            $nip = $_POST['nip'];

            $number_of_files = sizeof($_FILES['berkas']['tmp_name']);

            $cek = 0;
            for($i=0;$i<$number_of_files;$i++)
            {
                $namaBerkas[$i] = $nip."-".($i+1).".jpg";

                $config['upload_path']          = base_url().'assets/upload/';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size']             = 1000;
                $config['max_width']            = 2024;
                $config['max_height']           = 1200;
                $config['file_name']            = $namaBerkas;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                // $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if ($this->upload->do_upload()){
                    $cek = $cek +1;
                }
                print_r($config);
                echo $cek;
                die();

            }

            if($cek == 2){
                if($this->m_main->uploadFile($nip,$namaBerkas[0],[1])){
                    echo "<script> alert ('Upload Berkas Berhasi!');</script>";
                    redirect('admin/C_main/beranda');
                }
            }

        }
```

this is my model

```
function upload_file($nip, $berkas1, $berkas2){
            $sql = "update daftar set PATH1 = $berkas1, PATH2 = $berkas2 WHERE NIP = $nip";
            return $this->db2->query($sql);
        }
```

the output of code above is: You did not select a file to upload.

Comment: Initialize your upload. remove // on $this->upload->initialize($config);

Comment: already try that but still got the same output "you did not select a file to upload." @Ritchie

Comment: what does your query print?

Comment: $check is not increase on this
if ($this->upload->do_upload()){
               $cek = $cek +1;
}

so i cant executed query

Comment: Why do u have two from fields with the same name (name="berkas[]") ?

Comment: Because i want to get multiple file

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you have two same form fields. Try this

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/c_main/uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputFile">Berkas 1</label>
<input type="hidden" name="nip" id="nipUpload" value="">
<input type="file" class="filestyle" name="berkas[]" data-buttonText="Find file" id="berkas[]">
<p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Upload File</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: i want to upload 2 files and insert to field in table
where table structure
| NIP | NAME | PATH1 | PATH2 |

Comment: select multiple files, loop through. Use $_FILES["berkas"]['name'] to get file name and pathinfo($_FILES["berkas"]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION); to get file extension. that should work. remove comment on $this->upload->initialize($config);

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/c_main/uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">Berkas 1</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="nip" id="nipUpload" value="">
            <input type="file" class="filestyle" name="berkas" data-buttonText="Find file" id="berkas">
            <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">Berkas 2</label>
            <input type="file" class="filestyle" name="berkas1" data-buttonText="Find file" id="berkas1">
            <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
  </div>

          <div class="row">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Upload File</button>
          </div>
</form>
```

**Conrtoller**

```
function uploadFile()
        {
            $nip = $_POST['nip'];

            $number_of_files = sizeof($_FILES['berkas']['tmp_name']);

            $cek = 0;                
            $namaBerkas = $nip."-".1.".jpg";

                $config['upload_path']          = base_url().'assets/upload/';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size']             = 1000;
                $config['max_width']            = 2024;
                $config['max_height']           = 1200;

                $config['file_name']            = $namaBerkas;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                // $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if ($this->upload->do_upload('berkas')){
                    $cek = $cek +1;
                }

                $namaBerkas1 = $nip."-".2.".jpg";
                $config['file_name'] = $namaBerkas1;
                if ($this->upload->do_upload('berkas1')){
                    $cek = $cek +1;
                }

                print_r($config);
                echo $cek;
                die();



            if($cek == 2){
                if($this->m_main->uploadFile($nip,$namaBerkas[0],[1])){
                    echo "<script> alert ('Upload Berkas Berhasi!');</script>";
                    redirect('admin/C_main/beranda');
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still not working,
I tried to print $cek, but its value still 0.
I think the problem is in this code "$this->upload->doUpload()" because value of $cek is not changed, but i dont know whats wrong with the code.

Comment: Have you change $this->upload->doUpload() to $this->upload->doUpload('berkas')?